# build/generated/source/apollo dictory not be generate

Tags: android, graphql

[image]

this is my project sturcture.the project from eclipse project, i want use graphQL,everything is ok,but build/generated/source/apollo dictory did not create.what should i do.for the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if the "build/generated/source/apollo" directory already exist. If it is then check if the directory is "read-only"

Answer (score 0):

my project sturcture is bad,because my project is from eclipse,change the sturture .